# mySQL - comparing values to other records in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database that takes the below form. It displays price information by product and day for a number of competitor sites (comp_site). I am trying to get the difference between the competitors price and the site price for the days were the information exists.

[image]

The required output would look like the below:

[image: required output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a table with itself, just give an alias to be able to distinguish between the two copies of the table :

```sql
SELECT p1.comp_site, p1.product, p1.price, ..., (p1.price - p2.price) as difference
  FROM products p1
   JOIN products p2 ON p1.product = p2.product AND p1.date = p2.date 
    -- not sure I understood your requirement for the condition of the JOIN
  WHERE p2.comp_site = 398
  ORDER BY ....
```

(you can also `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` or ...)